# Asterisk Phpagi DTMF

Tags: asterisk, dtmf

I have been searching around but I can't seem to find the answer. I want to see if what I want to do is possible:

I want to playback music on hold to my caller when my phpagi script is executed. Is there anyway I can grab any DTMF that is being pressed during the musiconhold? I want the music to play continuously....

Any kind of insight I can get on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $AGI->stream_file($filename, $digits) ([voip-info](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+perl+agi))

or something like:

```
while ($digit ne "0") {
     $digit = $AGI->get_data("path/to/your/file", 1, 1);
     do your staff
     ...
}
```

I used it in Perl, but probably same thing for phpagi. 
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello, so will it play the entire file or will it stop if somebody press something?

Comment: can we not make it stop the playback?

Comment: It will stop Playback \ on DTMF recived if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too late to answer but this may help someone. Background music will keep on playing until you stop it.

```
// start background music
$agi->set_music(true);

//code....do your stuff

// stop background music
$agi->set_music(false);
```